Expectation and variance of Y
Let $X$ be an exponential random variable with mean $1$. Let $Y$ be a uniform random variable over the interval $(0,X)$. We were asked to calculate the mean and variance of $Y$. The mean of $Y$ is easy. I reasoned that if $Y$ is uniform and goes from $0$ to $X$, then its mean is simply arithmetic mean of $0$ and $E(X) = 1$. Thus, the mean of $Y$ is $\frac{1}{2}$.
However, I'm slightly less certain about the variance of $Y$. I reasoned that $E(X^2) = Var(X) + [E(X)]^2 = 1 + 1 = 2$. Then, $E(Y^2) = \frac{0 + E(X^2)}{2} = 1$ (not sure if this step is right...). Finally, I concluded that $Var(Y) = 1 - 0.5^2 = 0.75$. Is this reasoning correct?

How do you know $Var(X)=1$?

@RedFive An exponential random variable with rate $\lambda$ has expectation and standard deviation $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ and here $\lambda=1$

Right. I forgot that it was exponential. Thanks.

$E(Y^2) \not = \frac{0 + E(X^2)}{2}$ here so not $1$.  It is in fact $\frac23$.

@Henry Ah, I knew something was not right there

You could use the law of total variance, which says that $$\operatorname{Var}[Y]=E[\operatorname{Var}[Y|X]]+\operatorname{Var}[E[Y|X]]$$
As $Y|\{X=x\}\sim U(0,x)$, we have that $$E[Y|X]=\dfrac{X}{2},\quad\operatorname{Var}[Y|X]=\dfrac{X^2}{12}$$
Using that $X\sim\operatorname{Exp}(1)$, we find $$\operatorname{Var}[E[Y|X]]=\dfrac{\operatorname{Var}[X]}{4}=\dfrac{1}{4}\\E[\operatorname{Var}[Y|X]]=\dfrac{E[X^2]}{12}=\dfrac{\operatorname{Var}[X]+E[X]^2}{12}=\dfrac{2}{12}=\dfrac{1}{6}$$
Thus, $\operatorname{Var}[Y]=\dfrac{1}{4}+\dfrac{1}{6}=\dfrac{5}{12}$.

Yup this makes sense! We were taught the law of total expectation but I guess I did not have enough practice with it to come up with this solution. Thanks!

Forget the formulas! We have  $Y=UX$ where $U$ is uniform on $(0,1)$ and is independent of $X$. Therefore the  variance of $UX$ is $$\frac{1}{3}\times 2-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=\frac{5}{12}.$$
